# How can I copy data from one Excel workbook to another Excel workbook using variables for Workbook and Worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried this code, but I can't figure out how to use the variable for Worksheet. Can someone help? Thanks a lot!

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
    Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbDest = Workbooks("DestinationWB.xlsx")
    
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("DestinationWB.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    wbDest.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = _
    wbSource.wsDest.Range("A1").Value
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi braX, many thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
    Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbDest = Workbooks("DestinationWB.xlsx")
    
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    wsDest.Range("A1").Value = wsSource.Range("A1").Value
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi CDP1802, thank you very much for your appreciated support! It works!